# SQL Server Pivot/Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a way to convert this table I have that has sorted everything in columns into rows

```
EmpID       Day             StartTime
-------------------------------------------------
  4       SUNDAY           10:00:00 AM
  4       MONDAY            8:00:00 AM
  4       TUESDAY           8:00:00 AM
  4       WEDNESDAY         8:00:00 AM
  4       THURSDAY          8:00:00 AM
  4       FRIDAY            NULL
  4       SATURDAY          NULL
 800      SUNDAY           10:00:00 AM
 800      MONDAY            8:00:00 AM
 800      TUESDAY           8:00:00 AM
 800      WEDNESDAY         8:00:00 AM
 800      THURSDAY          8:00:00 AM
 800      FRIDAY            NULL
 800      SATURDAY          NULL
```

INTO

```
EmpID       Sunday(Start Time)      Monday(Start Time)         
-------------------------------------------------
  4          10:00:00 AM             8:00:00 AM
```

etc...

I've seen examples of Pivot and Unpivot, but would this be to complex for the pivot/unpivot function?

Comment: Please update you post to make it clear that you are only looking for pivot/unpivot solutions so people don't waste their time writing alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use PIVOT

**Example**

```
 Select *
  From  YourTable src
  Pivot ( max(StartTime) for Day in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday] )  ) pvt
```

**Note:**  This assumes `YourTable` is the 3 columns as displayed in your sample.  If you have extra columns, `YourTable` should be replaced with a sub-query such as

`From (Select EmpID,Day,StartTime From YourTable) src`

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select empid,
       max(case when day = 'Sunday' then StartTime end) as Sunday_StartTime,
       max(case when day = 'Monday' then StartTime end) as Monday_StartTime,
       . . .
from t
group by empid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am looking for a pivot/unpivot alternative. for learning purposes